# MS Access 2010- How to fit my back ground image to screen size?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having a Background which I kept in the form of an image and used the format option to send the image to back (Send to Back option).

Now I have placed many controls over the image.

The UI looks correct in my system. But when it's displayed on a monitor with different screen size the image gets shrinked and the controls are misplaced.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using the wrong method to add a background image to your form. Do not add an image control, use the form properties. Stretch will make the picture cover your form and resize with the form.

[image: form picture]